# How to let array mean be NaN if columns contain NaNs

Tags: numpy

We know:

```
>>> a = np.array([[1, np.nan], [3, 4]])
>>> np.nanmean(a, axis=0)
array([ 2.,  4.])
```

But how to let the result be

```
array([ 2.,  np.nan])
```

Comment: `np.mean(a, axis=0)` or `a.mean(axis=0)` ?

Comment: Thank you MaxU. It works!  LOL